# Программ-ярлык для Google Play Маркет и App Store

Tags: android, ios

Мне надо создать программку, которая при запуске будет запускать браузер с нужным `url` на `android` и `ios` устройствах, больше никаких действий делать ей не надо.
Понимаю, что вопрос очень простой, но я работаю с `php`, для данных устройств никогда ничего не писал.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, с чего начинать здесь?

Comment: думаю, вам проще будет заказать это на фриланс-бирже. Точно проще, чем изучать iOS И ANdroid разработку

Comment: браузер должен открываться в самом приложении, или приложение должно перейти в браузер?

Comment: перейти в браузер

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для Android почитайте про `intent`. По вопросу, открытие ссылки в браузере:

```
String url = "http://www.example.com";
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(i);
```

аналогичное действие iOS:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.example.com"]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Или же можете добавить `UIWebView`, тогда `url` отобразиться в приложении без необходимости переходить в браузер.

Answer (score 0):

Для iOS никак т.к. Apple, скорее всего, заблокирует программу если вся ее функциональность будет состоять из редиректа или webView